# I needed hostname to run sql php script to connect but my hosting company gave me PuTTY with SSH, now I'm lost?

Tags: php, mysql, ssh, putty

```
define("HOST", "need this host name");
define("USER", "");
define("PASS", "");
define("DATA", "");
```

Need something like mysql.10web.com but instead SSH and Putty, been trying to understand and implement but lost. Can anyone explain how to make this thing work

Answer (score 0):

most of hosting companies Mysql server are localhost accessible only, have you tried :

```
define("HOST", "localhost");
```